# Finding consecutive letters in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I have the following sequence: `'TATAAAAAAATGACA'` and I want Python to print out the letter containing the most consecutive repeats... which would be 7 `'A'`s in this scenario. How would you be able to do that using just `for`, `if`, `len`, `range`, and a counting variable?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. What have you tried, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def consecutiveLetters(word):
    currentMaxCount = 1
    maxChar = ''
    tempCount = 1

    for i in range(0, len(word) - 2):
        if(word[i] == word[i+1]):
            tempCount += 1
            if tempCount > currentMaxCount:
                currentMaxCount = tempCount
                maxChar = word[i]
        else:
            currentMaxCount = 1

    return [maxChar,tempCount]

result = consecutiveLetters("TATAAAAAAATGACA")

print("The max consecutive letter is ", result[0] , " that appears ", result[1], " times.")
```

This will print: `The max consecutive letter is  A  that appears  7  times.`

Comment: Sorry my confusion, I can get my code to also print out 'A' but I can't get it to print "7". Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it!